# Assembled program gives error: /a.out: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: assembly, x86, ubuntu-14.04, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I'm new to coding 64-bit x86, but I am running Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty), and I have a very simple 64-bit piece of code that I assemble using *as*. The output I get has strange permissions and file type.

When I run:

```
as file.s
```

I get a file `a.out` with 770 permissions.

I get this error when I execute it:

> bash: ./a.out: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

When I run:

```
file ./a.out
```

I get:

> ./a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB  relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped

The assembly code I am using is:

```
.section    .data
.LC0:
    .string "/bin/sh"

.LC1:
    .string "/bin/sh"

.LC3:
    .quad .LC1, 0

    .text
    .globl  _start
_start:
.LFB0:

    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp

    movq    $59,%rax     # System Call to execve
    movq    $.LC0, %rdi  # Pass program to execute
    movq    $.LC3, %rsi  # Pass command line arguments
    syscall

    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to assemble the program with GNU Assembler (*AS*) first and then use the linker to generate the final executable. To do that you should be able to use something like:

```
as file.s -o file.o
ld file.o -o file
```

The first command tells the assembler to output an *ELF64* object called `file.o` using the `-o` option. The second command links `file.o` to a 64-bit ELF executable called `file` using the `-o` option.

The typical default behaviour on a 64-bit system is for the assembler and linker to generate 64-bit objects and executables.

You can then run it with:

```
./file
```

Comment: Thanks, I assumed since it generated an a.out file it had attempted to link, as gas used to generate a .o file when you provided no specific name. I had tried running ld on a.out without options, and similarly that didn't work ( I am guessing because it was trying to read and write to the same file). In any event, thank you for answering.